# How to speed up signup with react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm working on an ecommerce website. Sign up for membership takes quite a long time (3-5 seconds). Is there any way to make it faster?

this is my signup.jsx

I think I have written all parts but the booking process is too slow when applying. In firebase the database is stored. But I don't know why the code is slow.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Helmet from '../components/Helmet/Helmet'
import { Container,Row,Col, FormGroup } from 'reactstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import '../styles/login.css'
import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import {auth} from '../firebase.config'
import {setDoc, doc} from 'firebase/firestore'
import {db} from '../firebase.config' 
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'


const Signup = () => {

  const [username,setUsername] = useState('')
  const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('')
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false)

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const signup = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setLoading(true)

    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
        )


        const user = userCredential.user




          // store user data
          await setDoc(doc(db,'users',user.uid),{
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: username,
            email,

          })
        



        setLoading(false)
        toast.success('Account created')
        navigate('/login')
    } catch (error){
      setLoading(false)
      toast.error('something went wrong')
    }
  }

  return (
    <Helmet title='Signup'>
      <section>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            {
          loading? (<Col lg='12' className='text-center'><h5
          className='fw-bold'>Loading... 
            </h5></Col> ):(            <Col lg='6 ' className='m-auto text-center'>
              <h3 className='fw-bold mb-4'>Signup</h3>

              <form className='auth__form ' onSubmit={signup}>
                <FormGroup className='form__group'>
                  <input 
                  type='text' 
                  placeholder='Usermane'
                  value={username} 
                  onChange={(e)=> setUsername(e.target.value)}  />                                                                                                       
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className='form__group'>
                  <input 
                  type='email' 
                  placeholder='Enter your email'
                  value={email} 
                  onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}  />                                                      
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup className='form__group'>
                  <input 
                  type='password' 
                  placeholder='Enter your password'
                  value={password} 
                  onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)}  />                                                      
                </FormGroup>




                <button type="submit"  className='buy__btn auth__btn'>Create an Account</button>
                <p>
                  Already have an account? {''}
                  <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>                                                                       
                </p>
              </form>
            </Col>)
          }
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>

    </Helmet>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

If I can get relevant examples it will be very helpful